# Xdebug on server can not connect to my computer

Tags: xdebug, phpstorm

I am using PhpStorm for development in Windows 7. I am trying to setup xdebug.

I installed xdebug to server by using pecl.

I added these codes to php.ini

```
zend_extension="/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/xdebug.

xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=212.2XX.179.83
xdebug.remote_port=9001
xdebug.idekey="PHPSTORM"
xdebug.remote_log=/tmp/xdebug.log
```

phpinfo() shows Xdebug running.

when i use;

```
netstat -aon | more
```

on cmd I can see that its listining in port 9001

```
 TCP    0.0.0.0:9001           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4908
```

But Xdebug can not connect to PhpStorm

xdebug.log shows that it can not connect to my ip:port

```
Log opened at 2013-05-02 17:20:55  
I: Connecting to configured address/port: 212.2XX.179.83:9001.
E: Could not connect to client. :-(
Log closed at 2013-05-02 17:20:58

Log opened at 2013-05-02 17:20:58
I: Connecting to configured address/port: 212.2XX.179.83:9001.
E: Could not connect to client. :-(
Log closed at 2013-05-02 17:21:16

Log opened at 2013-05-02 17:21:16
I: Connecting to configured address/port: 212.2XX.179.83:9001.
E: Could not connect to client. :-(
Log closed at 2013-05-02 17:21:19
```

I runned;

```
nc -v 212.2XX.179.83 9001
```

on the server and it answers

```
nc: connect to 212.2XX.179.83 port 9001 (tcp) failed: Connection timed out
```

I am working on this for 2 days and can not find a solution.

Any help about debugging why server can not connect to ip would be great. Thanks

EDIT: Problem fixed, It seems there was a problem with my server and we had to reinstall firewall csf

Comment: **1)** Does PhpStorm actually listens on that 9001 port? Maybe some another app already uses it .. or you set the wrong port in PhpStorm (by default it uses standard 9000); **2)** If you behind firewall/router, make sure that you opened/forwarded that port to your computer; **3)** Is IP address 100% correct? It should be **your** IP as seen by the server (e.g. from `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`).

Comment: 1) Phpstorm listens on port 9001, i am sure, i use tcpview and it shows that Phpstorm.exe using that port. 3-) Ip address 100% correct 2-)I am not using any firewall, how can i make sure that port is accesible?

Comment: So .. you are behind the router, right? or not?

Comment: Yes I am behind the router

Comment: Well ... you need to configure your router to always redirect ALL incoming packets on 9001 port to YOUR computer (**port forwarding**). How to do this -- it depends on the actual router model -- just google instruction for your model; each manufacturer can use different name for this functionality. **Alternatively:** use SSH tunnel. Check this link as well -- it has references to all of these: http://matthardy.net/blog/configuring-phpstorm-xdebug-dbgp-proxy-settings-remote-debugging-multiple-users/

Comment: If unsure about port forwarding -- give me the link to the router manual and I will tell you how that feature called there and what to do (as long as manual is half decent and has screenshot or two). **P.S.** There was a website full with such instructions for almost all router models ... but I cannot find it right now (no longer exist??)

Comment: I have set up the port forwarding, i added it like this ; Rule Name : xdebug   Client IP : 205.XXX.91.127(this is my server ip)   Active : Active WAN TCP Ports : 9001 WAN UDP Ports : 9001 LAN TCP Ports : 9001 LAN UDP Ports : 9001 LAN Interface : VLAN1  WAN Interface : VC1 . But server still cant connect to me. I also tried to setup SSH tunnel but it also didnt work. Any more ideas?

Comment: I also tried with http://canyouseeme.org/ and it also cant connect to my ip on port 9001. It says Error: I could not see your service on 151.2XX.240.227 on port (9001)
Reason: Connection timed out .

Comment: I do not think that you doing this port forwarding correctly: In all home/office level hardware routers I have worked with, the client IP would be IP of your computer ON LAN (e.g. 192.168.0.5); it has nothing to do with your server (unless your router is advanced one and can also restrict what external IPs can connect to this port. Example: http://matthardy.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/port-forward.png

Comment: I changed ip to my ip and saved still no luck, I dont have to restart modem after this ip modification right? Because if i restart my ip changes and the ip i entered before will be unusefull

Comment: It's clearly that either you still have not done port forwarding properly .. or you have firewall somewhere that prevents from connecting (that's considering that all other settings are set up correctly). I cannot help you here any further: I'm not there and do not see what exactly you have done. **BTW**: If your IP is constantly changing, then it is definitely will be better to use SSH (and maybe XDebug Proxy) as no client IP will be necessary in such case (only server one). GL further.

Comment: It seems i had problem with port forwarding like you said, the problem was in client ip i was using my own machines ip and not the ipv4 ip. I got ipv4 ip with ipconfig command , now other internet services can see my computer but not my server, nc command still shows connection timed out.